# Elasticsearch must_not not working with filter clause

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am working on medical project, where I have multiple questions along with the topics attached to them. The problem is that the following code works fine but it does not consider the 'must_not' filter, whereas it works fine with 'must' clause. Help me out with this.

```
GET stopdata/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "question": "Hello Dr. Iam suffering from fever with cough nd cold since 3 days"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "topics": [
                  "fever",
                  "cough"
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "topics": [
                  "children",
                  "child",
                  "childrens health"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "random_score": {}
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I need to convert the code to Java, which I am trying but stuck with following code.

```
Set<String> mustNot = new HashSet<String>();
mustNot.add("child");
mustNot.add("children");
mustNot.add("childrens health");

Set<String> must = new HashSet<String>();
must.add("fever");
must.add("cough");

FunctionScoreQueryBuilder fsqb = new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("question", "Hello Dr. Iam suffering from fever with cough nd cold since 3 days"));
fsqb.add(ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction((new Date()).getTime()));

BoolQueryBuilder bqb = boolQuery()
        .mustNot(termsQuery("topics", mustNot));

SearchResponse response1 = client.prepareSearch("stopdata")
        .setQuery(fsqb)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();

System.out.println(response1.getHits().getTotalHits());
```

The mapping of the 'stopdata' index is as follow

```
{
   "stopdata": {
      "mappings": {
         "questions": {
            "properties": {
               "answers": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "id": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "question": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "my_english"
               },
               "relevantQuestions": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "topics": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Adding the sample data for the above index

```
"question": "My son of age 8 months is suffering from cough and cold and fever. What treatment I have to follow?"
"topics": [
  "Cough",
  "Fever",
  "Hydration",
  "Nutrition",
  "Tens",
  "Childrens health"
]

"question": "Hi.My daughter, 4 years old , has on and of fever  with severe coughing and colds for 3 days now.She vomited as well last night.Do you think it's viral?"
"topics": [
  "Vomiting",
  "Flu",
  "Cough",
  "Fever",
  "Pneumonia",
  "Meningitis",
  "Tamiflu",
  "Incision",
  "Childrens health",
  "Oseltamivir"
]

"question": "If you have a fever of 101 with chills and sweats for 2 day with a slight cough, should you go to the drs or let is wear off?"
"topics": [
  "Cough",
  "Fever"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing I see is that the whole `filter` part is misplaced, it should go inside the `filtered` query, because there is no `filter` element at the root of the `function_score` element (see [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)). So your query should look like this in the first place + you should use POST instead of GET since you're sending a payload:

```
POST stopdata/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "question": "Hello Dr. Iam suffering from fever with cough nd cold since 3 days"
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "topics": [
                      "fever",
                      "cough"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "topics": [
                      "children",
                      "child",
                      "childrens health"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "random_score": {}
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Now to write all this in Java, it goes like this:

```
Set<String> mustNot = new HashSet<String>();
mustNot.add("child");
mustNot.add("children");
mustNot.add("childrens health");

Set<String> must = new HashSet<String>();
must.add("fever");
must.add("cough");

MatchQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("question", "Hello Dr. Iam suffering from fever with cough nd cold since 3 days");

BoolFilterBuilder filter = FilterBuilders.boolFilter()
    .must(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("topics", must))
    .mustNot(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("topics", mustNot));

FilteredQueryBuilder fqb = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(query, filter);

FunctionScoreQueryBuilder fsqb = QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(fqb);
fsqb.add(ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction((new Date()).getTime()));

SearchResponse response1 = client.prepareSearch("stopdata")
        .setQuery(fsqb)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();

System.out.println(response1.getHits().getTotalHits());
```

**UPDATE**

The reason why the `must_not` doesn't match `childrens health` is because the `topics` field is analyzed and thus the `Childrens health` gets tokenized and analyzed as two tokens `childrens` and `health`, thus trying a `terms` match on `childrens health` will not yield anything. Maybe, splitting into two terms would help:

```
              "must_not": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "topics": [
                      "children",
                      "child",
                      "childrens", 
                      "health"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
```

Comment: I still get the results with topics 'childrens health', there is no change in the result as you have suggested.

Comment: I was merely fixing 1) a semantic issue in your query and 2) helping you build the Java equivalent. In the end, what is matched depends on your data and how your mapping for the `topics` field looks like, feel free to share more info on that.

Comment: Thank you for the help Val. I have added the mapping and the sample data. Also, I am getting the error in `FilteredQueryBuilder fqb = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(query, filter);` `'The method filteredQuery(QueryBuilder, FilterBuilder) in the type QueryBuilders is not applicable for the arguments (MatchQueryBuilder, BoolQueryBuilder)'`

Comment: What version of ES are you running by the way?

Comment: You need to edit your question and not my answer :) I've rejected both edits and edited your question instead. Feel free to wrap it up.

Comment: Another error popup `The method must(FilterBuilder) in the type BoolFilterBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (TermsQueryBuilder)`

Comment: It worked by using `BoolFilterBuilder filter = FilterBuilders.boolFilter()
      .must(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("topics", must))
      .mustNot(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("topics", mustNot));`

Comment: Ok, another good catch. Sorry I was typing this from memory, but I must be rusty :)